# How to send more elements trough fifo in c

Tags: c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int td,i=0;
char msg[256];

main(){
    if(fork()==0){
        td=open("testfifo",O_WRONLY);
        while(i!=7){
            write(td,"something",256);
            i++;
        }
        write(td,"something else",256);
    }
    td=open("testfifo",O_RDONLY);
    read(td,msg,256);
    printf("%s\n",msg);
}
```

I want to send trough fifo, the message "something", 7 times and then "something else" but it prints:

```
something
something
```

What am i doing wrong, or why is it not printing all ?

Comment: You write the full buffer size 8 times, but read it only once. Try doing `write(td, "something", 9);` and be more thoughtful of the 0-byte. You cannot expect printf to print anything past the 0-byte that terminates the strings.

Comment: Now i understand thank you.

Comment: Variables `i` and `td` (and frankly `msg` too) should be local variables in `main()`.  You should be writing 21st Century C — that means using C99 or later, and not using implicit return type on `main()`.  You should write `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or equivalents — the return type is mandatory in 21st Century C.  Also, by writing 256 characters from a string literal containing 10 including the null byte, you are indulging in undefined behaviour.  You get anything you get; you deserve to have the program crash.

Comment: Note that `write()` doesn't write strings; it writes arbitrary length buffers with arbitrary data in them.  It doesn't know about null bytes or care or need to care about them, or any other byte value.

Comment: I get it now, thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the read manpage

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of
>          file),  and the file position is advanced by this number.  It is not an
>          error if this number is smaller than the  number  of  bytes  requested;
>          this  may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available
>          right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file,  or  because  we
>          are  reading  from  a  pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was
>          interrupted by a signal.  See also NOTES.

`read` is returning only the string `"something"` because that's what's been put into the pipe the first time, then the program falls out of the `if` statement and reads the second `"something"` and finishes

if you want to read everything in the pipe then you need to call `read` from within a loop (and also probably `return` at the end of the `if` statement).